# Cap icemaker water line under sink-cap leaks

Tags: plumbing, water, ice-maker, tape

Following the suggestions on this site, I bought a 1/4" compression cap for the unused icemaker water line under the sink.  After installing it with Teflon tape, water is still spewing out.  I noticed that the icemaker line I removed has a male piece that plugs into the supply line and then a female nut to tighten it to the line.  Is there a cap that would have such a piece that would go into the line to improve the fit?

Comment: A picture of the fitting you're trying to cap off would be most helpful. Also, is there a valve on the ice maker line that's separate from the regular water line valve? If so, just shut that one off.

Comment: Most of those valves use compression fittings so a cap may not seal well because of the straight threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end of tubing that you want to cap you should have a fitting similar to this [image]

Additionally, add insert one of these into the tube after the nut and compression ferrule have been placed on the tube[image]

Tighten the nut onto the couplers body only until the bottoms out or stops turning. Brass nut will crack from over-torquing. Remove the other nut and ferrule from the couplers other end. Wrap (2) turns of teflon tape in a clockwise direction on these threads. Tighten a compression cap
[image]
using directions as mentioned for nut above.

Compression fittings have a "finer" thread than standard International Pipe Thread (IPT).